# Restrict input to specific characters

Tags: jquery, input, keycode

I'd like to restrict an input field to any letter, a period and a hyphen.

I thought the following would allow the input of any letter but it's not allowing anything to be inputted. It's probably something obvious that I'm overlooking.

```
$('input').on('keypress', function(event){
    if (event.keyCode > 65 || event.keyCode < 90)
        return false;
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you can use a Regular Expression to compare the entered text to the values you want to allow and remove any you do not. You should also use the `keyup` event when checking the value. You can also use the `input`, `blur` and `paste` events to make sure all events are covered for all browsers. Try this:

```js
$('input').on('input blur keyup paste', function() {
  $(this).val(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(/[^a-z\.-]/ig, '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="foo" type="text" />
```

Comment: Is this solution better than a `preventDefault()` solution? Which one is faster/better?

Comment: `preventDefault()` won't work for the `paste` event, which should be taken in to account as it's very easy to get around a `keydown`/`keyup` event based restriction

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the **numbers** only then try this:

```
$('#text').keypress(function (e) {
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]\-.+$");
var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
if (regex.test(str)) {
    return true;
}

e.preventDefault();
return false;
});
```

Comment: Numbers? OP explicitly states: `restrict an input field to any letter, a period and a hyphen`

Comment: Updated the regular expression.